# How to add Mapbox telemetry to android?

Tags: android, mapbox-android

did com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry got deprecated , cause the MapboxNavigation item is asking for it, but i cant find it, thanks

Comment: This smells like a request for docs.  Have you tried looking here: https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/navigation/overview/#mapboxnavigation-object

Comment: yes i did, i even copy the whole code and i had the same issue, I am about to write them an email, I need the locationEngine, I know where to find it, but when i try to use it in MapboxNavigation it ask for the location engine that is in the telemetry folder, thanks